# Unable to open Display settings in Linux Mint with Cinnamon after plugging in a docking station with a monitor connected via HDMI

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, monitors, dock-station

I'm experiencing difficulties with getting a second monitor to function on my laptop. I connect the monitor to a docking station using HDMI, and the docking station is then connected to my laptop via USB-C.

The docking station functions properly since the USB ports work as expected, and I don't encounter this issue when using other computers.

The monitor displays the Mint logo for a brief period upon turning on the laptop but ceases to function after the login screen is loaded.

I've tried opening the Cinnamon settings via a terminal, and this is the error that I've got:

```bash
$ cinnamon-settings
Using PAM module (python3-pam)
Loading Display module
**
CinnamonDesktop:ERROR:../libcinnamon-desktop/gnome-rr-config.c:733:gnome_rr_config_load_current: assertion failed: (gnome_rr_config_match (config, config))
Bail out! CinnamonDesktop:ERROR:../libcinnamon-desktop/gnome-rr-config.c:733:gnome_rr_config_load_current: assertion failed: (gnome_rr_config_match (config, config))
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've tried removing existing configurations from `~/.config/cinnamon-monitors.xml`, but it had no effect. `xrandr --auto` outputs `xrandr: cannot find preferred mode`. The same monitor works when connected through HDML directly to the laptop, but ideally I'd like to use USB-C instead. I'm using Nvidia drivers version 515.105.01.

Is there anything I could do to fix the USB-C monitor connection?